# middle extended to right end div

Tags: html, css

Here is my layout's top:
[image]

the Blue portion has the css code as follows:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:960px;
background-image:url(images/ribbon.png);
```

The yellow is fine as it is empty, but i need the red to continue the ribbon all the way to the page's right end but i'm not sure how to go about doing it. Any help would be appreciated.

code:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4086656/index.php
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4086656/main.css

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here; can you describe it in a little more detail or post some code using http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Can't really say anything unless we know the HTML for the yellow, blue, and red sections, and the CSS rules you have applied to each.

Comment: The yellow has not code, nor does the red. i've modified the post with the code files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give the `body` or the parent of the blue portion a repeating background, the ribbon, and make a separate image for the background of the blue portion (with a black background where there's no ribbon).

Comment: Hmmm, I would keep the blue portion centred then? I'm sorry I may not quite understand what you mean.

Comment: I am only suggesting using 2 different backgrounds, one for the whole `body` and one for the blue section that *overwrites* the `body` background. It will change nothing in your positioning.

Comment: wouldn't that create a bar that extends from the yellow through blue and red? Sorry Jeroed i still don't quite understand.

Comment: I think i got what you meant - i gave the body the same background and then used a push div.